# How to write/get "long long int" to/from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

In my app I have `long long int` variable: `9999999999` and I need to write it and then get it to/from `NSUserDefaults`. Methods `setInteger:forKey:` and `integerForKey:`do not work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap the integer into a `NSNumber` object and use `setObject:forKey:`:

```
long long int val = 9999999999LL;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  setObject:@(val) forKey:@"key"];
```

Retrieving the value:

```
long long int val = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"key"] longLongValue];
```